# Get nearby BSSID and signal strength in Java

Tags: java, wifi, bssid

I need to get nearby BSSID's with their signal strength using Java.
Something like the output of `netsh wlan show networks mode=BSSID`.

Is it possible?

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes. "Is it easy?" Probably not. This will probably require platform specific code, so for what platform? Does your given command work on the platform? If so, you can execute that with a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Windows, well, mostly. Yes this command  work on windows, but i need a pure Java solution if possible. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Note that a "pure Java" solution is likely impossible without some JNI code, making it platform-specific.  Your best bet is using `netsh` via `ProcessBuilder` on Windows finding similar mechanisms for other OSes you need to target.

Comment: May God be with me for the parsing part of ProcessBuilder... Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a method like this: (of course the command held in the cmd string is for window operating systems only).

The "wlanResults.append("...");" is simply writing the **results** to a jTextArea in a gui (it's a part of a program i'm working on).

```
public void getWLANbssidInfo(){
     String cmd = "netsh wlan show network mode=bssid";

        try {

            Process p3;
             p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + cmd);
             p3.waitFor();
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p3.getInputStream()));
             String line = reader.readLine();
             while(line!=null){
                 wlanResults.append(line + "\n");
                 System.out.println(line);
                 line = reader.readLine();
             }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            wlanResults.append("Comand error\n" + ex);
            System.out.println("There was an IO exception.");

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            wlanResults.append("Command was interrupted: " + ex);
            System.out.println("The command was interrupted.");
        }

}
```