# How to check Wifi signal strength with Java but no on Android platform?

Tags: java, wifi

Is there any standard Java API or Java framework which will let me check WiFi signal strength in Java Application for Win/MacOS (not for Android)?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240305/get-nearby-bssid-and-signal-strength-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can write a java code to run tcpdump (linux) or windump(windows) and then extract wifi strength form that.

Here are some useful links

[Tcpdump Java code](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Measure_the_Received_Signal_Strength_of_WiFi_Beacons)

[Windump website](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/)